# Snippets comments are incorrectly parsed inside code blocks producing strange output

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, markdown-rendering

I was editing the following question, as the code blocks needed indenting, and noticed there was an problem with the html comments.

Post: [setOnItemClickListener for listview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33778407/1394393)

Here is the code I had to post, notice the space in I added in the comment start:

```
    <! -- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
    <! -- language: lang-html -->

    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

    <! -- end snippet -->
```

But if I removed the extra spaces, I see this instead of the correct content inside the code block in the preview:

```
<pre>a9f531e6-8396-9c2e-d3f7-c919790e0f57</pre>
```

If the post is saved, the server render will display the code correctly, but it will also put snippet controls within the code block itself.

But I can add multiple comments here without issue:

```
 <!-- Comment 1 -->
 <!-- Comment 2 -->
 <!-- Comment 3 -->
```

Can anyone explain this to me, or is this a SO bug?
If it is a bug, how do I report it?

Comment: _"If it is a bug, how do I report it?"_ You just did. :)

Comment: Thanks @Kendra. I'm new to Meta!

Comment: Is there a reason you're including Snippet code in an Android question? Snippets only work for HTML/JS/CSS, and I'm pretty sure those comments wouldn't work in a Java file, but I don't really know Android.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I don't know. I was editing the question as a reviewer, it was not my question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Karl here was just the editor, from the looks of it. The OP of the post he edited originally had his code blocks as snippets.

Comment: Karl, @Kendra, my apologies, I was unclear on that. I've put in my vote of approval for your edit to remove the extra comments, Kendra :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's cool, and I noticed. :) (I try to keep an eye on my suggested edits, so I can see what happens and hopefully learn from any rejections.)

Comment: Nice find! Some markdown parsers uses hashes or guids to temporarily stand-in for a value that will be substituted back later. You've somehow hit a path that confuses the parser's state so it never substitutes the real value back.

Comment: I gave the post a more precise title and added my own observation (that the server-side rendering doesn't produce the same effect, but the result is still incorrect). Feel free to edit/revert if you don't like the changes.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Thanks for the edit. :-)