# Bug (?) with stack-snippets within three backticks

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, stack-snippets, markdown

<sub>First off: I'm not sure if that's actually a bug. Just seemed really odd.</sub>

---

I was reviewing some suggested edits and came across the [following edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28539456) (which I rejected):

[image: Screenshot_1]

---

Then I decided to view the rendered Markdown:

[image: Screenshot_2]

---

The first button does nothing, the second one produces the normal output. 
As I said, I don't know if that's actually a bug because the post is very poorly formatted. 
The snippet is within the three backticks.

But I think snippets shouldn't be rendered within backticks anyway, because I noticed another thing while creating this very post:

I wanted to include the edited post as text in this question, which wasn't possible:

[image: Screenshot_3]

Yields:

[image: Screenshot_4]

So should snippets within code tags just not be rendered at all?

Comment: Related: [Snippets comments are incorrectly parsed inside code blocks producing strange output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310537/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Ah, that would explain the second part of my question. Thanks!

Comment: In fairness, the markups sort of conflict with each other. I'm not sure it's not expected to get an unexpected result. It would be better to probably get a more meaningful failure but it's likely still to be a failure.

Comment: There’s another post I was trying to find: this deleted one: [Stack snippet looks strange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405816/4642212) ([<10k screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feU8N.png)). Also related: [Stack Snippets delimiters are being parsed too eagerly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284254/4642212).